# Reference sheet name via cell inside Excel formula

Tags: excel

As you can see in the image or formula below, I am writing a series of formulas that are referencing the sheet "Lulu."  Instead of rewriting "Lulu" over and over, I would like to write Lulu **once** in cell B1 and reference cell B1 inside the formula.

```
=AVERAGE(LULU!$C$4:$C$5)/AVERAGE(LULU!$D$4:$D$5)-1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDIRECT(), but this will be longer:

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("'" & B1 & "'!$C$4:$C$5"))/AVERAGE(INDIRECT("'" & B1 & "'!$D$4:$D$5"))-1
```